# Help - load numbers from a .txt file to variables (c++)

Tags: c++, variables, file-io, numbers

Program 2 should show 111, 222 and 333 as result for x,y,z.
I want to read the text file, line to line, and save one line to one variable
like: 
Line1 = x
Line2=y
Line3 =z
Can someone help me?

PROGRAM 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

float x, y, z;

int main()
{   
    x=111;
    y=222;
    z=333;
    ofstream meuarquivo;
    meuarquivo.open ("brasil.txt");
    meuarquivo << x << "\n";
    meuarquivo << y << "\n";
    meuarquivo << z << "\n";

    meuarquivo.close ();

    return 0;
}
```

PROGRAM 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

float x, y, z;


int main(){ 
    x=0;
    y=0;
    z=0;

    char nomedoarquivo[90];
    ifstream objeto;
    cin.getline (nomedoarquivo, 90);

    objeto.open (nomedoarquivo);

    if (!objeto.is_open ()){
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);}

    while (objeto.good()){
        string r;
        objeto >>r;

    }

    cout << "\n" << x << "\n" << y << "\n" << z << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When loading floating-point types, mind the decimal separator, which is not "." in every locale, and could lead to loading values which are not correct in some locales, hence, bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The second program needs to read input from a file. But the program isn't opening the file the first program has written to.

1. Have a std::vector to store the strings that are read from file.
2. Open the file in read mode, which the first program has written text to, as a part of first program.
3. `push_back` the each read string to the vector until the end of file is reached.
4. Iterate through the vector and convert `std::string` using `atoi`.

   `int readNumber = atoi((*iter).c_str()) ;`

This should give you an idea.

Comment: You can use extraction operators directly, without using atoi: `int n; objeto >> n;`

Answer (score 1):

The code segment

```
while (objeto.good()){
    string r;
    objeto >>r;
}
```

basically means that you are reading in each number as a string, and discarding it immediately when the loop scope ends. Instead I would suggest creating an float array of size three, reading into them using the loop, and then assigning the values of each of the elements to x, y and z, like so:

```
float vals[3];
int i = 0;
while (objeto.good()) {
    objeto >> vals[i];
    i++;
}
x = vals[0]; y = vals[1]; z = vals[2];
```